# How to bind canvas to scrollViewer properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, scrollviewer

I want to bind `canvas` component with `scrollViewer`. I have a function that zoom in and out my `canvas`, and I want to add scrollbars using `scrollViewer` that match my `canvas` actual size.

Zoom in/out function for my canvas:

```
private void canvasShopMap_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                scaleTransform.ScaleX += scaleRate;
                scaleTransform.ScaleY += scaleRate;

            }
            else
            {
                scaleTransform.ScaleX -= scaleRate;
                scaleTransform.ScaleY -= scaleRate;

            }

            canvasShopMap.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
        }
```

XAML code I tried to do (yes, I know that scrollViewer is inside canvas here, but I tried the function above for scrollViewer and it doesn't work ;/ ):

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvasShopMap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="690" MouseLeftButtonDown="canvasShopMap_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseWheel="canvasShopMap_MouseWheel" Margin="272,139,0,0">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewerForCanvas" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          Height="{Binding Parent.ActualHeight , Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                          Width="{Binding Parent.ActualWidth , Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" MouseWheel="scrollViewerForCanvas_MouseWheel">               
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Canvas>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what you are trying to do ? if you increase sviewer size along with canvas, then there is no need for sviewer.

Comment: _"I know that canvas is inside scrollViewer here"_ -- what? The code you posted shows the `ScrollViewer` inside the `Canvas`, not the other way around. It is difficult to understand your question. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise description of what the code does and what you'd like it to do instead.

Comment: Sorry, edited. Briefly, I want to have canvas inside a scrollViewer. I want to have option to zoom in/zoom out and two scroll bars to move the position of the insreased picture.

Comment: You'll have to put the canvas inside the scrollviewer - the other way around isn't going to work. Apparently that didn't work for you, but what exactly do you mean with 'doesn't work'? What result did you get?

Comment: When I putted canvas intro a scrollviewer, I had a scroll bars, but they was working only for the original size of the picture. I mean that if I increased my canvas(with mouse scrolling), scroll bars didn't change their ranged for a bigger picture.